# FPS Lag scheduler?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I've been getting FPS lag. I've looked around and people say to use

```
[self schedule:@selector(gameLoop:) interval: 1/60.0f];
```

When I use this I get choppy lag. but when I use

```
[self schedule:@selector(gameLoop:)];
```

It's a lot smoother. Here is a snippet of my movement code.

```
- (void)gameLoop :(ccTime)dt
{
    [self manageCannon:dt];
    [self manageBullets:dt];
    [self manageEnemies:dt];
    [self manageAllies:dt];
}
- (void) manageEnemies :(ccTime)dt
{
    enemyClass *tempEnemy;
    for(int i = 0; i < [enemies count]; i++)
    {
        tempEnemy = [enemyClass new];
        tempEnemy = [enemies objectAtIndex:i];

        tempEnemy.position = ccp(tempEnemy.position.x-tempEnemy.speed*dt,tempEnemy.position.y);

        if((tempEnemy.position.x - tempEnemy.range) < [wall getwally])
        {
            tempEnemy.speed = 0;
        }
        if(tempEnemy.health < 1)
        {
            tempEnemy.alive = false;
        }

        if(tempEnemy.alive == false)
        {
            [enemies removeObjectAtIndex:i];
            [tempEnemy removeFromParentAndCleanup:true];
        }
    }
}
```

I always try to write my own code from scratch, so if you can help me out with other things that i'm doing that is incorrect that would be very helpful towards me.

Comment: don't schedule with an interval, the scheduler is already tied to the framerate so it won't work any better, and at worst it will execute the selector only every other frame

Comment: ps: use Instruments and find out what exactly is slowing down your app.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say what is slowing down your app from the information given.  As LearnCocos2D suggested, you can use Instruments to figure out where the slow stuff is.  Or if you want to get very granular analysis, you can always use the following macros in your code:

```
#define TIC start = [NSDate date]
#define TOC -[start timeIntervalSinceNow]
#define TOCP NSLog(@"TIME: %f", TOC)
```

Before using, be sure to declare `NSDate *start` in scope of use.  Then just put a series of TIC/TOC or TIC/TOCP pairs in your code to print out times your code is taking in different places.  You can very quickly find the bottlenecks this way.